# How to compute $I(n)=\int_{0}^{\pi}x \sin^n(x)\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to collect some hints for computing
$$I(n)=\int_{0}^{\pi}x \sin^n(x)\,dx$$
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Compute by parts and establish a recurrence relation

Comment: @Shailesh: better to exploit symmetry.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. Thanks. I realised that my hint would take much longer and be messier. Your solution as usual is elegant

Comment: $I(n) = \pi \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^n(x)\,dx=\pi W_n$ where $W_n$ are the [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual symmetry trick works just fine. $\sin(\pi -x)=\sin(x)$, hence:

$$ I(n) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-x)\sin^n(x)\,dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}x\sin^n(x)\,dx\right]=\pi \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^n(x)\,dx $$
but:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^n(x)\,dx &=& \int_{0}^{1} u^n(1-u^2)^{-1/2}\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}v^{(n-1)/2}(1-v)^{-1/2}\,dv\\&=&\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\,\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}\end{eqnarray*} $$
so:

> $$ I(n) = \color{red}{\frac{\pi\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}}.$$