# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin ^{n}(\eta) d \eta$?

Tags: integration

I have encountered the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin ^{n}(\eta) d \eta=\underbrace{\left[\left(\sin ^{n-1}(\eta)\right)(-\cos (\eta))\right]_{\eta=0}^{\pi}}_{=0} -\int_{0}^{\pi}\left((n-1) \sin ^{n-2}(\eta) \cos (\eta)\right)(-\cos (\eta)) d \eta$$

But I'm not getting how did the integral evaluate to become what is on the right side of the above equation. I am trying to do integration by parts but in vain. Could you please show me the missing steps?

The right hand side can then be simplified to look like:
$$=(n-1) \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos ^{2}(\eta) \sin ^{n-2}(\eta) d \eta$$

Comment: No, it's integration by parts with $u=\sin^{n-1}(x),\,\mathrm{d}v=\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x,\,v=-\cos(x)$. Would you please provide your integration by parts so we see where did you stuck and can point in right direction? Thanks.

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575737/a-sinn-x-integral).

Comment: Thanks, @AlexeyBurdin. With your suggested substitutions, I've have been able to reach the right side. I wasn't using the right substitutions earlier.

Comment: @Axion004, no I wasn't looking for the form of the right-hand side given in that question. My question was different.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3600745/wallis-product-with-integrals?r=SearchResults&s=6|54.5476

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute $I(n)=\int_{0}^{\pi}x \sin^n(x)\,dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786843/how-to-compute-in-int-0-pix-sinnx-dx)

Comment: @an4s, nopes, it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key observation here is that you can write $\sin^{n}(\eta) = \sin^{n-1}(\eta)\sin(\eta).$  Then, to integrate by parts, we let

\begin{alignat}{3}
u &= \sin^{n-1}(\eta) &&\implies du &&= (n-1)\sin^{n-2}(\eta)\cos(\eta)\\
dv &= \sin(\eta) &&\implies v &&= -\cos(\eta).
\end{alignat}

Then, we get

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{n}(\eta)\,d\eta  = \left[\sin^{n-1}(\eta)(-\cos(\eta))\right]\bigg|_{0}^{\pi} -\int_{0}^{\pi}\left((n-1) \sin ^{n-2}(\eta) \cos (\eta)\right)(-\cos (\eta))\, d\eta.$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin ^{n}(\eta) d \eta=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin ^{n}(\eta) d \eta + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \sin ^{n}(\eta) d \eta$$
Put $\eta \rightarrow \eta + \pi/2$ in the second integral to get:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin ^{n}(\eta) d \eta=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin ^{n}(\eta) d \eta + \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos ^{n}(\eta) d \eta$$
$$=\beta((n+1)/2, 1/2)$$
$$=\frac{\Gamma((n+1)/2)\sqrt\pi}{\Gamma(n/2 + 1)}$$